# Spring boot Junit testing for putMapping returns always null

Tags: spring-boot, junit, spring-boot-test

I have a `PutMapping` that would first check the `Reward-Entity` and then if exists, it would further proceed to update the `Entity`

```
@PutMapping
public ResponseEntity<RewardResponse> updateValidReward(Principal updatedPrincipal,
                                                                @RequestBody RewardUpdateRequest rewardUpdateRequest) {

            Optional<RewardEntity> rewardEntityInDatabase =
                RewardService.getRewardById(rewardUpdateRequest.getRewardId());

        if (!rewardEntityInDatabase.isPresent()) {
                return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }

        RewardEntity updatedReward = updateReward(updatedPrincipal,
                rewardUpdateRequest, rewardEntityInDatabase.get());

        RewardResponse updatedRewardResponse = RewardResponse.builder()
                .reward(RewardMapper.fromRewardEntity(updatedReward))
                .build();

        return ResponseEntity.ok(updatedRewardResponse);
}
```

This is now challenging for me when i attempt to write a `Test-case` for this, in the below format

```
ResponseEntity<RewardResponse> rewardResponse =
                controller.updateValidReward(principal, rewardUpdateRequest);


        RewardApi rewardApiToValidate = rewardResponse.getBody().getReward();
        assertThat(rewardApiExpected.getRewardTitle()).isEqualTo(rewardApiToValidate.getRewardTitle());
        assertThat(rewardApiExpected.getRewardText()).isEqualTo(rewardApiToValidate.getRewardText());
```

I always get `NullPointerException` when the below line in test-code gets executed

`rewardResponse.getBody().getReward();`

because always the below-condition in the actual code becomes `true` and it is always returning `HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND`

```
if (!rewardEntityInDatabase.isPresent()) {
                    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
            }
```

How to tackle this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tackled this by calling exactly what the `Controller` in original code is doing.. First, i called `Optional --> getRewardIdFromDatabase()` code stuff through my test code i executed the `update` method of the Controller